# tensor flow character recognition with softmax results in accuracy 1 due to [NaN...NaN] prediction

Tags: tensorflow, softmax

I am trying to use the softmax regression method discussed in https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners to recognize characters.

My code is as follows.

```
train_data = pd.read_csv('CharDataSet/train.csv')
print(train_data.shape)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 130])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([130, 26]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([26]))

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 26])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

for _ in range(10):
  batch_xs = train_data.iloc[:, 2:]
  print(batch_xs)
  batch_ys = getencodedbatch(train_data.iloc[:, 1])
  print(batch_ys)
  sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
```

However, I am getting an accuracy of 1, which shouldn't be the case. 
The reason why I am getting it so is because my y tensor results with an array like

```
[nan, ..., nan]
```

Can anyone explain to me what is wrong in my code?

I converted each character to a one-hot encoding using the method below

```
def getencodedbatch(param):
    s = (param.shape[0],26)
    y_encode = np.zeros(s)
    row=0
    # print(y_encode)
    for val in param:
        col = ord(val)-97
        y_encode[row, col] = 1
        row += 1
    return pd.DataFrame(y_encode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem you are having:

- You set your initial weights and biases to 0 (this is wrong, as your
  network does not learn).
- The result is that y consists of all zeros
- You take the log of y.. and a log of 0 is not defined... Hence the NaN.

Good luck!

Edit to tell you how to fix it: look for an example on classifying MNIST characters and see what they do. You probably want to initialise your weights to be random normals ;)